# Doctrine PHP 8 Attributes

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm, symfony5

I use PHP8, Symfony 5.2 and Doctrine 3.0 in my project,
But the PHP 8 attributes, allowed since [Doctrine 2.9](https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/2.9/reference/attributes-reference.html), doesn't seem to work.

```php
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping\Entity;

**
* @Entity(repositoryClass="App\Repository\MyClassRepository")
*/
class MyClass
{
```

works fine.

```php
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping\Entity;

#[Entity(repositoryClass: MyClassRepository::class)]
class MyClass
{
```

Return `[critical] Uncaught PHP Exception Doctrine\ORM\Mapping\MappingException: "Class "App\Entity\MyClass" is not a valid entity or mapped super class." at .../vendor/doctrine/orm/lib/Doctrine/ORM/Mapping/MappingException.php line 378`

here is my composer.json :

```json
"composer/package-versions-deprecated": "1.11.99.1",
"doctrine/doctrine-bundle": "^2.3",
"doctrine/doctrine-migrations-bundle": "^3.1",
"doctrine/orm": "^3.0",
"symfony/console": "5.2.*",
"symfony/dotenv": "5.2.*",
"symfony/flex": "^1.3.1",
"symfony/framework-bundle": "5.2.*",
"symfony/proxy-manager-bridge": "5.2.*",
"symfony/yaml": "5.2.*"
```

Comment: Maybe because 3.0 has not been released yet?  I would imagine the doctrine bundle would need at least a few tweaks.

Comment: Have you imported `MyClassRepository`?

Comment: @Cerad, yeah, I think you're right. Probably the doctrine bundle needs a few adjustments. Thanks.

Comment: @miken32, what do you mean by imported ?

Comment: PHP 8 attributes for Doctrine ORM Symfony configuration was not fully supported until `doctrine/doctrine-bundle` [2.4+](https://github.com/doctrine/DoctrineBundle/blob/2.4.x/Resources/config/orm.xml#L38).  `^2.3` should install it, but it may have been locked prior. The Symfony doctrine mapping type declaration config still  defaults to `annotation`.

Answer (score 5):

This is because of doctrine bundle configuration. If all entities within the bundle use attributes just switch the metadata driver from "annotation" to "attribute"

```yaml
doctrine:
    orm:
        auto_generate_proxy_classes: true
        entity_managers:
            default:
                ...
                mappings:
                    MyBundle:
                        type: attribute
```

If some entities within a bundles use attributes and some others annotations - than it is better either choose only one format for metadata or implement a custom metadata driver.

Comment: Here is the Symfony documentation for any who are wanting, [Doctrine Config Reference](https://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/configuration/doctrine.html#type). It is important to note the documentation for PHP 8 attributes support was added in Symfony 5.3+

Answer (score 2):

The solution is use a custom AnnotationDriver.

Sample fully works implementation: https://github.com/baraja-core/doctrine/blob/master/src/Orm/Mapping/AnnotationDriver.php